# How i can convert NSString to long value?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, long-integer

I have one value `100023` and I have taken it in `NSString`.

Now I want to pass this value in my web service which contains long parameter type so how can I convert string value to long.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use `NSString` methods `intValue` `longLongValue`.

Answer (score 25):

For a small number like this "100023", this is acceptable with 'longlongvalue'. However, if the number digits have more than >10 in which commonly regard as the use case for long value. Then, you will run in into this problem, such as:

```
String value "86200054340607012013"
```

do

```
@"86200054340607012013" integerValue or intValue
```

you will produce this in the print statement

```
2147483647
```

if you do

```
@"86200054340607012013" longlongvalue
```

you will produce this in the print statement

```
9223372036854775807
```

This works for me and print out the expected number.

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:@"2394739287439284734723"];
NSLog(@"longlong: %llu", [myNumber longLongValue]);
```

Answer (score 14):

Use this:

```
    yourLong = [yourString longLongValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the **doubleValue** Method to avoid lose of precision warnings

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

```
float floatId = [strID floatValue];
```

Answer (score -12):

Do this...

```
long value = [myString longValue]
```

Comment: Don't do this because this cause the exeption: "unrecognized selector sent to instance". Use "- (long long)longLongValue;" or "- (int)intValue;" instead.